# Sharing a Google Document with multiple email addresses and preventing recipients from seeing the list of email addresses

Tags: privacy, google-docs

Is there any way to share a Google Document with multiple email addresses in such a way that recipients cannot see the list of email addresses I shared the document with?

By default upon sharing the Google Document, all recipients are CC in the same e-mails (well done Google...). I would like them to be BCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to share a document from within Google Documents and have it BCC all the recipients.  This is a feature that has been requested a lot over the past several years on the Google product forums (e.g. [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HhTxxHaFMCA), [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/MWMuZk6cy6g/4mRY16hYqHsJ), [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/P-d_yADl-Mo), and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/SzforasAzZo/aEbzb3y4Ip4J)), and so far Google has not implemented it.

I saw a couple people in those threads mention a workaround that will only work if you want to share a document to people with "can view" access.  In that case, you share the document with "Can view" access to everyone but do not select the "Notify people via email" box.  Then you take the link to the document and send it in a regular email to everyone in the Bcc line.

That workaround will not work if you want to share a document to people with "can edit" access.  This is because anyone with edit access can click on the document's "Share" button and see all the other editors' email addresses.

Comment: The UI is shamefully lacking. Sad I can believe Google did not at least go with sane defaults there.

Comment: I was in search of this much needed feature and ran across this answer.  I'm pretty sure that even with View Only access when the user is viewing the document the UI will display the user details.  So if multiple "BCC" viewers happen to be viewing the same document, there goes the privacy I need.